# Close button on div

Tags: jquery, html, button

I have a div toggled on various links with a close button. 
Unfortunately, the close button is not behaving like it should, as its linked with absolute position and so not connected to the div itself.  When I put it in position:relative, it adds a new button in the div on every new opening.
This must be peanuts, I know, but myy knowledge is quite basic, so help is much appreciated! 
Thanks MrGreen

> SCRIPT

```
$(function(){
    $(".action").click (function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var target = $this.data('content');

        $('.action').not($this).each(function(){
            var $other = $(this);
            var otherTarget = $other.data('content');
            $(otherTarget).hide(400);
        });

        var cls = $('<div/>', {
            'style':'left:843px;top:15px;width:12px;height:18px;cursor:pointer;padding:3px;position:absolute;border:solid gray 0px;background-color:',
            'id':'cls',
            'text':'x',
            'title':'Close',
            'click':function(){
                var t=$(this);
                t.parent().hide(400, function(){
                    t.remove();
                });
            }
        });

        $(target).prepend(cls).show({height: "toggle"},400);
    });
});
```

Comment: show us  html markup, may be jsfiddle ?

Comment: I think you might have slightly the wrong approach, it looks like u are creating the button everytime, perhaps you need a more settled solution.  a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would really help make this easier to fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you keeping adding/removing the close buttons?

I'd suggest you use something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', ".action", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var target = $this.data('content');
    $(target).toggle();

    $('.action').not($this).each(function() {
        var $other = $(this);
        var otherTarget = $other.data('content');
        $(otherTarget).hide(400);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.close', function(){
        $(this).parent().hide(400);
    });

});
```

Full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/EMYFt/5/

This way, you keep the HTML intact, and just toggle the elements visibility in response to clicks on links / close buttons..

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, you want to remove target. That should work, just use `next()` instead of `parent()` div and insert before the element :

```
$(function(){

$("div.action").click (function(){
var $this = $(this);
var target = $this.data('content');
$('div.action').not($this).each(function(){
    var $other = $(this);
    var otherTarget = $other.data('content');
    $(otherTarget).hide(400);
});
var cls=$('<div/>', {
   'style':'left:843px;top:15px;width:12px;height:18px;cursor:pointer;padding:3px;position:absolute;border:solid gray 0px;background-color:',
   'id':'cls',
   'text':'x',
   'title':'Close',
   'click':function(){
        var t=$(this);
        t.next().hide(400, function(){
            t.remove();
        });
    }
});
$(target).before(cls).show({height: "toggle"},400);
});
});
```

simplifed sample: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/tASL5/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".action").on("click", function(e) {
        var $targ = $(this).data("content");

        $(".action").not($(this)).each(function(i) { $($(this).data("content")).stop().hide(400); });

        //  you should really consider adding a class and changing the jQuery styleing to be a style on a style sheet or in head
        if ($targ.children(".cls") == 0) {  //  cls element does not exist
            $targ.prepend(
                $("<div />").prop({ id: "cls", title: "Close" })
                    .addClass("cls")    //  this is par my suggestion to add a class name variable
                    .css({ left: '843px', top: '15px', width: '12px', height: '18px', cursor: 'pointer', padding: '3px', position: 'absolute', border: 'solid gray 0px', background-color: 'white' }) // not needed if you take my suggestion
                    .text("x")
            );
            $targ.children(".cls").click(function(e) {
                $(this).parent().stop().hide(400, function(e) {
                    //  $(this).children(".cls").remove();
                    //  why remove this?
                });
            });
        };

        $targ.show({ height: "toggle" }, 400);
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks Guys! redSahdow's Code is exactly what I wanted, problem now is, on my Wordpress-Site the div .content is closingitself imediately after showing. In jsFiddle it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/EMYFt/6/

Comment: @user1805817 My works BlueCoat protec is being a #$%^$, so i can't really look at it till i get home, but you may wanna check you're not making a "double" call on the click event.  I'm unsure you're setup at this moment, but [**e.stopPropagation()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) might help.  
Also, Be sure to check the answer that works for ya and give +1's to helpfuls. && Welcome to StackOverflow, now go set up your account! :P